# Create a new blog post using AtomPub and .NET

Tags: .net, blogs, atompub

I need to create a new blog post from an application I am writing.  Currently the target bloging engine is BlogEngine.net and probably WordPress in the near future.  It was suggested to me to use AtomPub for this, but I am having a difficult time determining what I need to to to crate a a new blog post.  I am hoping that going the AtomPub route will allow the app to post to most bloging engines.  I am not looking to do anything fancy; basically just need subject and content and perhaps categories or tags.

Most of the examples I am finding are for creating or reading feeds.  This is not what I am currently looking to do.  An example or a link to an example will be very helpful to get this started.

If there is a better route for me to follow to achieve this, please suggest it.  I really don't have a lot of knowledge in this area.

The application is written in C# (.NET 4)

Comment: Looks OData will handle this, still reading...

Comment: Did you ever find out more on this?

Comment: I ended up using XML-RPC,http://XML-RPC.NET for c#/vb. I don't think it's the same as AtomPub--this whole splace is a bit blurry. Many blog engines support XML-RPC. I have successfully written blog entries to BlogEngine.NET, WordPress, and MovableType (+Type Pad). Had some trouble with Blogger, still need to figure that out and try some more engines.  The free online application is at http://blogbyemail.com.